# Is the discriminant $\Delta=b^2-4ac$ of a quadratic equation a linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, discriminant

If you consider the discriminant $\Delta= b^2-4ac$ of a quadratic equation as a linear transformation, what does it requiere to prove it?

Context: Linear Algebra course.

I tried by myself to prove it, using two conditions of linear transformations:
$$T(u+v)=T(u)+T(u) $$ And,
$$T(\lambda  u)= \lambda T(  u)$$
 I need to prove it.Suggestions to verify the proof? .Thanks in advance.

Comment: A linear transformation of what? Of the trinomial coefficients maybe? But then it's not linear, quite obviously.

Comment: We can't verify your proof if you don't show it !

Comment: I did something similar, for instance , determinant of order 2 is a linear transformation, of course it is not a LT, because Determinant doesnt hold its properties to verify the Linear Transformation.

Comment: You re right, I mean that I need suggestions to verify a LT. I m not native speaker. Sometimes is difficult to explain my questions. But  I do my best.

Comment: $b^2-4ac$ is the determinant $\begin{vmatrix}b&2a\\2c&b\end{vmatrix}$.

Comment: No. It's a different question. I provide you an example of a similar exercise . I mean, it is a similar proof verification. In this case I consider $b^2-4ac$ as discriminat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. For example, multiplying each coefficient of the quadratic equation by $k\ne0$, while leaving its roots unchanged, multiplies $\Delta$ by $k^2$. This is because $\Delta$ is a [homogeneous polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function#Homogeneous_polynomials) in the coefficients of degree $2$. (By contrast, $\sqrt{\Delta}$ is a homogeneous function of degree $1$, albeit not a polynomial one. In both cases, "degree" is short for *degree of homogeneity*.) Other transformations of the coefficients will in general have even more complicated effects on $\Delta$.